# Python - PIP - VENV - Proxy - OSError no scheme, but I have the scheme in the URL?

Tags: python, pip, proxy, python-3.9

This one is a bit baffling and head pounding to me.

Windows 10
Python 3.9.6
Behind a Proxy, have the proxy details in the User variables in windows both http and https
Proxy is using Windows AD as auth.

I'm using venv to create different virtual environments its been a while since I have created one.  Prior to this having the user variable everything works fine, main python and pip installation can install packages no problem.  I even have 2 or 3 venv environments that work no issue, I think on one I had to do --proxy in the pip line to work.

However with new environments with venv and pip 21.1.3, getting the error:"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://".

I've tried with and with out both http:// and https:// with --proxy in the pip install command still getting the error.  I go back to my old venv environments and it works just fine no errors. I've tried a pip.ini file with proxy=[proxyurl:port] (hidden due to privacy) also HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY. I believe I set them as global, user, site at different tries.

Why on the new ones is this happening but the old ones works fine, and how to fixit, since I put the scheme in and it doesn't want to work.